# PYTHON Login in with multiple account using Gmail api/imaplib

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I'm currently working on an application requiring a gmail inbox. Currently i'm using the Gmail API with a credentials.json and a token.pickle and this is working fine although I want to login with other credentials each time the script is used. I'm quite new to this API and was wondering if it's possible to login with other credentials than the credentials used for the token.pickle.

**Gmail API**

To currently get a gmail inbox I use the following code:

```
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    global service
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

**Imaplib**

Another way I've tried to get a certain user's inbox is with the imaplib and email library since it lets you login with a certain email address and password. But to allow this to work a user needs to allow less secure apps to their google account which is a hassle for each user to enable that. The code I used for imaplib is the following code:

```
import imaplib, email


username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'


con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)

con.login(username, password)

con.select('Inbox')
```

**Question**

My question is: Is it possible with the gmail api from google to login with multiple/other credentials to get the corresponding gmail inbox? If this is not possible and I have to use the Imaplib way, what are the steps I need to take so it doesn't require users to enable less secure apps?

Comment: **# Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)**
Your code is storing the credentials for each user that logs in.  Remove that and it will request access of the user every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the .pickle file name. This code possibilite do this just changing the `user` variable. There will be different tokens to each account

```py
def api_connection(user):
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists(f'{user}.pickle'):
        with open(f'{user}.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', scopes)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open(f'{user}.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    return service
```